# Sql Server consuming lot of memory Creating Bottleneck for my web application Hosted in the same server

Tags: sql-server, performance-tuning, temporary-tables, memory-optimized-tables

HI I have a server with 64 GB Ram and I have assigned around 52GB to the SQl Server itself. However Even this has effected the  performance of the server and the web application hosted in the same server is performing poorly because of this, Can anyone suggest me a way to handle this situation

I can give you some of the major activities that can effect server
A)I Constantly import(dump) 5million plus records 3 hour , Compare it to the current 7 Million records and process the new ones.  I use lot of temporary tables for this process ... are these reasons for my bottle neck if so what can i do?

b) My web applications and database server are on the same server is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer your second question first, which is typically it's ideal to host your SQL Server instance on its own dedicated server, to maximize the resources it has available to it without causing contention for other applications or battling contention from other applications.

The **Memory**, **CPU**, **I/O**, and **Disk Space** available on the server are all key resources utilized by a SQL Server instance, and some of them are even *eagerly* acquired and held onto to maximize efficiency and performance of that SQL Server instance. For example, SQL Server will generally continually acquire more **Memory** (out of the total allocated to the instance) over time for multiple uses of caching, and generally won't release that **Memory** back to the server, unless the Windows OS indicates a critical **Memory** pressure event, or the server or instance is restarted.

To answer your first question, we can't accurately tell you the issue you're currently facing without more details and context, unfortunately. It's too complicated, and broad of a question, without observing actual concrete examples with metrics. But if you're certain
your SQL Server instance is affecting performance of your web application, then you're likely under-provisioned resource-wise. 12 GB of **Memory** sounds suspiciously low for both the OS (which likely needs a minimum of 4 GB itself) and the web application itself.

Aside from that, I wouldn't doubt you're seeing other resource contention either from the **CPU** or **I/O**. Your best bet is to try to isolate a specific example of a performance issue your web application is experiencing so that it's reproducible, and then measuring what's actively running on your SQL Server instance concurrent to those performance issues of the application. I find Adam Machanic's [`sp_whoisactive`](http://whoisactive.com/) very helpful as a starting point to see what is currently running on my SQL Server at any given instant.